# The job failed. The owner (pc\user) of job FULL DB BACKUP does not have server access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

SQL Server 2008R2 is failing to execute log backup hourly.

> Date      5/2/2013 10:22:19 PM
>  Log       Job History (LOG BACKUP)
>
> Step ID       0
>  Server       pc
>  Job Name        LOG BACKUP
>  Step
>   Name      (Job outcome)
>  Duration     00:00:03
>  Sql Severity      0
>   Sql Message ID        0
>  Operator Emailed     
>  Operator Net
>   sent      
>  Operator Paged        
>  Retries Attempted     0
>
> Message
>  The job failed.  The owner (pc\user) of job LOG BACKUP
>   does not have server access.

---

ps: its a windows 7 x86 ultimate virtual machine.
the account have administrator privilege.
any idea why its failing?

Comment: Where does the account have 'adminstrator' privileges?  Note, server privileges and SQL privileges are different and just because the account is a SQL admin doesn't mean it is a server admin.  Also, are you backing up to a local share or a network share?

Comment: It's a local path, plus the windows user have sysadmin privilege.

Comment: By sysadmin, do you mean the SQL Server sysadmin?  This isn't the same as server/filesystem permissions.  What are the login's permissions on the backup location?

Comment: the user is a local administrator, am not thinking clear sorry

Comment: Have you tried executing a log backup using T-SQL logged in as this user to the same location?  If this fails, what error message do you get?

Comment: Are local administrators specifically designated as sysadmin? Or at least is this one? 2008 R2 discontinued the practice of automatically adding BUILTIN\Local Administrators to sysadmin.

Comment: using SSMS the query runs smoothly under the job associated user account, since this user is stated initially in the installation wizard as an administrator within SQL Server. I changed the job to run under sa and start it, it runs fine, i switch to it temporary until i figure things out. as for @swasheck the user account supposedly (user) in this scenario is the only windows account in sysadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create the PC\user as a login and give him the backup privilege in your database with this code.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [SERVER\Test1] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
USE [mydb]
GO
CREATE USER [SERVER\Test1] FOR LOGIN [SERVER\Test1]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_backupoperator] ADD MEMBER [SERVER\Test1]
GO
```

Comment: sir, i know that very will, the user account is a sysadmin member, i just can't figure out why in gods sake things are going this way. I've already created another account, added a login, mapped a user to that login, added the user to db_backuporperator, and change the job's owner (exactly as you stated).

Comment: Can you provide the Windows Event log associated? My guess is the problem is not in SQL Server but it has to do with Windows. Which version are you using? Is your PC member of a domain?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue in SQL Server 2019.
My solution was changing the job Owner from the [domain\user] to `SQL Server Agent account`, and it worked.

[image]